I want to know how to implement JS eventListner classList's toggle function to change the class of the button written in Tailwind-css
<button id="btnAbt" class="absolute -ml-11 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 rotate-90 max-w-[160px] p-2 border-2 border-black rounded-lg font-bold shadow-2xl text-white text-2xl bg-cyan">
  About Me
</button>

Now I want it so that when I click the button, it switches its id from btnAbt to newAbt. It should use a JavaScript event but the code is written using Tailwind CSS. Page size should be same. It should only switch to another page while clicking on the button.
What I tried to do:
function aboutButton(){
    
    let target = document.querySelector("#btnAbt");
    target.classList.toggle("newAbt");
}
    
target.addEventListener('click',aboutButton);

I also added a new div in the same file.

You need to register the event-handler with the correct target ... document.querySelector('#btnAbt').addEventListener('click', handleAboutClick) ... your handler-function then can rely solely on the currentTarget-property of the event-object passed to the very handler ... function handleAboutClick(evt) { evt.currentTarget.classList.toggle('newAbt'); }

classList.toggle() is for adding/removing a class, not changing the ID.

Do you really need to change the id as opposed to a class?

I see you're trying to switch the id of a button when it's clicked and also navigate to another page. Let's get that working for you!
Here's the code to make it happen:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function aboutButton() {
            let target = document.querySelector("#btnAbt");
            if (target) {
                target.id = "newAbt";
                // Redirect to a new page
                window.location.href = "newpage.html"; // Replace with your new page URL
            }
        }
        
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            let target = document.querySelector("#btnAbt");
            if (target) {
                target.addEventListener('click', aboutButton);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnAbt" class="absolute -ml-11 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 rotate-90 max-w-[160px] p-2 border-2 border-black rounded-lg font-bold shadow-2xl text-white text-2xl bg-cyan">
        About Me
    </button>
</body>
</html>

Here’s what’s going on:
We define a function aboutButton that changes the button's id from btnAbt to newAbt and then navigates to a new page.
When the page loads, we add a click event listener to the button with the id btnAbt.
When the button is clicked, the function changes the id and redirects the user to newpage.html (make sure to replace this with the actual URL you want to navigate to).
This way, your button's id gets switched, and you’re taken to a new page, all in one smooth action.

Thanks buddy for the solution, I have one more doubt I'm currently using Tailwind CSS and want to display content only on screens of a specific size. When I add a new div with the ID newAbt in the same file, all the content inside the div will display by default, which isn't what I'm aiming for. In traditional CSS, I would define a new class like .newAbt{...} to manage this-with your code, but with Tailwind, I'm unsure. If I initially hide the content using the hidden class, could you guide me on how to unhide it later using JavaScript?
